# Javascript module syntax invoke contructor

Tags: javascript, module, constructor

I want to invoke a constructor method by using a function that is attached to the window object but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
// Modal.js
export default class Modal {
    constructor (...) {
        ....
    }
    ....
}

/ main.js
import Modal from './modules/Modal.js';
window.createModal = ??? // I tried new Modal / Modal / Modal.constructor but none of these work
```

Comment: You spelled 'default' wrong, for starts. Try looking at this for help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: In my code the word is right. This documentation doesn't even cover modules and the  window object.

Comment: window.createModal = () => new Modal();

Comment: Doesn't work :-(. It would't transfer the arguments from the constructor to the function.

Comment: just repass arguments: window.createModal = (...args) => new Modal(...args);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an instance on every call, wrap `new Modal` in a function and pass all the arguments of the function to the constructor:

```
window.createModal = (...args) => new Modal(...args);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//modal.js
export default class Modal{
    constructor(){
        console.log("Modal constructor...")
    }
}

//main.js
import Modal from './modal.js'
window.createModal= new Modal();
```